# NameError: name 'name' is not defined with request.POST.get on django views

Tags: python, django-views

iam trying to get data from form Post.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
class Seller(CreateView):
    fields = (name,)
    model = models.Seller

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.name = self.request.POST.get("name", "")+ "additional string" #concatenate string
        self.object.save()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

my template html

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

error from cmd

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: what is `fields = (name,)` ? And yes, `name` here is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a `django` expert, but what if you try to change this:

```
fields = (name,)
```

to that:

```
fields = ('name',)
```